# `pip3 search aiohttp` shows updated version, but won't install

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am installing a python package that depends on aiohttp, version >=3.  `pip3 search aiohttp` returns:

```
aiohttp (3.3.2)  - Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
  INSTALLED: 2.3.10
  LATEST:    3.3.2
```

So why does `pip3 install --upgrade --user aiohttp` respond that it's already up to date, and `pip3 install --user aiohttp==3.3.2` say:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp==3.3.2 [... snip ...] No matching distribution found for aiohttp==3.3.2
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Python v.3.5.2, and pip3 v.18.0.  The latter is an upgrade to the system's v.8.1.1 from the apt package python3-pip.  Pip3 was upgraded locally using `pip3 upgrade --user` so as not to conflict with the system packages.

Comment: pip search sucks for many reasons, and might be removed soon: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216

Comment: @wim - I see.  That, along with jwodder's answer (below), clarifies the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 3 of aiohttp requires Python to be at least version 3.5.3; [the documentation explains:](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new_3_0.html)

> Why not *3.5.0*? Because *3.5.3* has a crucial change: `asyncio.get_event_loop()` returns the running loop instead of *default*, which may be different, e.g.:
>
> ```
> loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
> loop.run_until_complete(f())
> ```
>
> Note, `asyncio.set_event_loop()` was not called and default loop is not equal to actually executed one.

As a result, pip running on Python 3.5.2 or any earlier version will ignore aiohttp v3 when installing; the fact that the newer version still shows up under `pip search` is arguably a bug.

Comment: I see, thank you.  Subsidiary question: could I somehow upgrade to python 3.5.3 using `--user`?  Or do I have to go to a virtual environment (which I've heard about but haven't yet figured out how to use)?

Comment: +1 see also the metadata, `"requires_python": ">=3.5.3"`, which makes [recent versions of] pip ignore it in here: https://pypi.org/pypi/aiohttp/json

Comment: @Diagon: No, you can't use pip to upgrade Python itself, and a virtualenv would only let you use the Python versions that are already on your system.